# Unir consultas para unir datos existentes y no existentes en Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? He tratado de unir dos consultas de listado de clientes.  Los existentes serian los que tienen huella dactilar y los inexistentes los que no tienen registrado en la tabla de Huellas.
ya he intentado con esto:

```
SELECT C.CodCliente,P.CI,P.Nombre,P.ApellidoPaterno,P.ApellidoMaterno,H.CodHuella,H.Huella,C.Estado 
FROM Cliente C 
INNER JOIN HuellaDactilar H ON H.CodCliente=C.CodCliente 
INNER JOIN Persona P ON P.CodPersona=C.CodCliente 
WHERE C.Estado='ACT'
union
SELECT C.CodCliente,P.CI,P.Nombre,P.ApellidoPaterno,P.ApellidoMaterno,'' as CodHuella,'' as Huella,C.Estado 
FROM Cliente C  
INNER JOIN Persona P ON P.CodPersona=C.CodCliente 
WHERE C.Estado='ACT'
```

Pero me salen registros repetidos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

incluso me sale el campo huella nulos en todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso lo hace solo el motor cambiando INNER JOIN, por LEFT JOIN.

Este es tú escenario:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.cliente
(CodCliente INT, 
 Estado     VARCHAR(3)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Persona
(CodPersona      INT, 
 CI              INT, 
 Nombre          VARCHAR(100), 
 ApellidoPaterno VARCHAR(100), 
 ApellidoMaterno VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.HuellaDactilar
(CodCliente INT, 
 CodHuella  INT, 
 Huella     VARCHAR(100)
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.cliente (CodCliente, Estado)
values
(59,'ACT'),
(60,'ACT'),
(61,'OTR'),
(62,'ACT'),
(63,'ACT');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Persona (CodPersona, CI, Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno)
values
(59,3500902,'Carlos'  ,'Veles'   ,'Mendes'),
(60,1111111,'Juan'    ,'Ruiz'    ,'Jos'   ),
(61,2222222,'Luis'    ,'Crisa'   ,'Siura' ),
(62,123456 ,'Pedro'   ,'Rocabado','Moreno'),
(63,654321 ,'M. Juana','Vaca'    ,'Lopez' );
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.HuellaDactilar
(CodCliente, CodHuella, Huella)
Values
(59,30,''),
(61,31,''),
(62,33,''),
(63,34,'');
GO
```

Con las tablas creadas y unas filas de ejemplo similares, a lo que has expuesto, la consulta se puede formar así:

```
SELECT C.CodCliente
 , P.CI
 , P.Nombre
 , P.ApellidoPaterno
 , P.ApellidoMaterno
 , H.CodHuella
 , H.Huella
 , C.Estado
FROM 
   Cliente C
   INNER JOIN Persona P ON P.CodPersona = C.CodCliente
   LEFT JOIN HuellaDactilar H ON H.CodCliente = C.CodCliente
     WHERE C.Estado = 'ACT';
```

Es importante que respestes el orden de union de los conjuntos. Primero con persona y luego con Huella Dactilar. Y luego esto ya depende de tí puedes tratar los resultados que para las columnas que menciona HuellaDactilar sean nulos de alguna manera.

[image: Resultados]

Por tanto el cliente 60 Juan no tiene registro en huellas dactilares. Si no quieres obtener un null, puedes utilizar en las columnas H.CodHuella y H.Huella la función IsNull(H.CodHuella, xx) donde xx es un int significativo para ti, como 0 o -1. Y IsNull(H.Huella,yy) donde yy es un varchar significativo para ti, como 'Inexistente'.
Te dejo un par de enlaces, donde tienes un detalle mayor sobre como se forman las consultas con left join

[Combinaciones de conjuntos](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/tag/combinaciones-de-tablas/)

[Left Join y no perder registros](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/09/01/left-join-entender-la-combinacion-de-izquierda-y-no-perder-registros/)